# Why is a TLD as domain accepted under RFC 822/Apache-commons validations?

Tags: java, apache-commons, email-validation, tld, rfc822

According to the Apache docs, their email validation respects the [RFC 822 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc822).

> EmailValidator provides email address validation according to RFC 822 standards.
> [source](https://EmailValidator%20provides%20email%20address%20validation%20according%20to%20RFC%20822%20standards.)

However when running some tests locally I found that some TLD's are accepted as a domain.

```
test@test      //invalid
test@test.com  //valid
test@com       //valid
test@comm      //invalid
test@amsterdam //valid
test@brussels  //valid
```

I thought I read somewhere in the RFC that `<local>@<domain>` is a valid e-mail address but highly discouraged to use (..and thus should be considered invalid?). So I get that `test@test` will not be valid, however `test@amsterdam` is, because `.amsterdam` is a valid gTLD.

Not sure if this is a bug or if this is intended. From their implementation and documentation it is unclear what should be valid, and if it is 100% comform the RFC 822 specification.

---

```java
class Test {
    EmailValidator validator = EmailValidator.getInstance(false, true);

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {
            "test@test",
            "test@test.com",
            "test@com",
            "test@comm",
            "test@amsterdam",
            "test@brussels"
    })
    void emails(String email) {
        System.out.printf("%-20s valid? %s%n", email, validator.isValid(email));
    }
}
```

What I also don't seem to get is what the parameters `allowLocal` and `allowTld` in the [`EmailValidator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html#EmailValidator-boolean-boolean-) constructor do

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is intended. You can adjust validation to your by providing parameters you've mentioned.

According to https://www.icann.org/en/announcements/details/new-gtld-dotless-domain-names-prohibited-30-8-2013-en dotless domains are prohibited.

And as a word of explanation for parameters:

- `allowLocal` - will allow local domains e.g `mail@somenotexistingtld`
- `allowTld` - will allow top level domains e.g `mail@com`

To have truly accurate RFC822 validation you need set both to `true`. But in real life scenario I would say that in most of the cases they will be omitted or set to `false`.